# SlidesJS - define number of slides to show?

Tags: jquery, slider, slideshow

I'm using [SlidesJS](http://slidesjs.com) and it works great, expect one thing - I cannot specify what number of slides to display at a time. Default is 1, so only 1 slide can be displayed.

Is it possible with this script to specify number of slides (for example I want to display 3 slides in the same time)?

Comment: sorry to be cynical but why would you display more than one slides at a time..if you want to display the hack would be to create two or what ever slides number of slides as 1 and display it that way..

Comment: create multiple slideshows with different offset and keep them in sync?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the demo code on the page, it looks like it is *sliding* the `<div>`'s instead of the `<img>`'s, which is good. If that is so, you should be able to do something like this:

```
<div id="slides">
    <div class="slides_container">
        <div>
            <img src="http://placehold.it/190x270">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/190x270">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/190x270">
        </div>
        <div>
            <img src="http://placehold.it/190x270">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/190x270">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/190x270">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And if the images don't want to `display:inline` nicely, you can always float them:

```
#slides img{
    float:left;
}
```

Comment: Great! float:left; should be removed however.

Comment: I only mentioned that in case the images weren't lined up next to each other. You could also force `display:inline`.